# Como agrupar elementos de diferentes columnas que comparten id?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-dplyr, dplyr

tengo un problema para hacer calculos ya que tengo id que se comparten pero en diferentes columnas, les pongo una muestra:

```
 Canton RODAL estra_def IdSP1 OcuSP1 IdSP2 OcuSP2 OcuSP3 IdSP3    N_mean   G_mean VCC_mean IAVC_mean Area_nueva
      6     a        11    45    100     0      0      0     0 365.68743 3.012912 3.686253 0.1617736       .68
      6     b        18    44     65    45     35      0     0        NA       NA       NA        NA      13.62
      6     c        13    46     40    45     30     30    44 132.47467 3.418930 6.714686 0.3388152      24.80
      6     d        18    45     50     0     30     20     0        NA       NA       NA        NA       6.12
      6     e        13    45     50    44     30     20    46  61.15057 3.566564 7.064443 0.3530676       1.30
```

Como muestra en la tabla, tengo un IdSp1 ( id de la especie 1) con su ocupacion en % (OcuSP1), IdSP2 ( id de la especie 2 ) con su ocupación  y un IdSP3 que pueden o no compartir la misma especie.

Entonces la IdSP1(NUMERO 45) ocupa un 100% en el rodal "a"

IdSP1(NUMERO 44) ocupa un 65% del rodal "b" , la IdSP2(NUMERO 45) ocupa un 35% del rodal b , etc.
Como ven, tengo en ese caso las 2 columnas que comparten el numero 45

La idea es colectar las especies iguales(numero de especie, ej 45) multiplicarlas por su ocupacion y luego dar un solo valor por especie, pero el problema es que no se como agrupar en esas 3 columnas de IdSP en un mismo ID, por ej todas las 45, o todas las 44 etc.

Probé realizando esto ( que viene de unas tablas previas) , pero luego me di cuenta que estaba sumariando por columna y no por especie, por lo que a partir de ahí estoy trancado.

```
 existencias_SP %>%
  summarise(N_tot = sum(N_SP1_tot, na.rm = T),
            N_ha = sum(N_SP1_ha, na.rm = T),
            G_tot= sum(G_SP1_tot, na.rm = T),
            G_ha = sum(G_SP1_ha, na.rm = T),
            VCC_tot = sum(VCC_SP1_tot, na.rm = T),
            VCC_ha = sum(VCC_SP1_ha, na.rm = T),
            IAVC_tot = sum(IAVC_SP1_tot, na.rm = T),
            IAVC_ha = sum(IAVC_SP1_ha, na.rm = T))
```

Mi idea es que quede el resultado asi

```
             N total G total VCC total IAVC total
Id Especie 1
Id Especie 2
Id Especie 3
```

Seria mejor arreglar la base de datos de alguna forma diferente o existe solucion para lo que necesito?

Gracias

**EDITO SEGUN LA RESPUESTA**

Bastian me recomendo generar 1 columna con `id_especie` pero se me genera el siguiente problema, ahora me genera un `id_especie de 0`, pongo el head

```
A tibble: 6 x 12
  Canton RODAL estra_def N_mean G_mean VCC_mean IAVC_mean Area_nueva especie id_especie Tipo_ocupacion valor_ocupacion
   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>        <dbl> <chr>                    <dbl>
1      6 a            11   366.   3.01     3.69     0.162       4.68 IdSP1           45 OcuSP1                     100
2      6 a            11   366.   3.01     3.69     0.162       4.68 IdSP1           45 OcuSP2                       0
3      6 a            11   366.   3.01     3.69     0.162       4.68 IdSP1           45 OcuSP3                       0
4      6 a            11   366.   3.01     3.69     0.162       4.68 IdSP2            0 OcuSP1                     100
5      6 a            11   366.   3.01     3.69     0.162       4.68 IdSP2            0 OcuSP2                       0
6      6 a            11   366.   3.01     3.69     0.162       4.68 IdSP2            0 OcuSP3                       0
```

YA filtre los 0, pero me di cuenta que esta generando por cada `idsp`  3 `Ocu` y así para todos, por lo tanto sigo sin dar con la solución

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te recomiendo es replantear la base en formato Long para poder hacer operaciones sobre agrupamientos, para ello una posible solucion seria hacer lo siguiente:

```
df1 = df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("IdSP1", "IdSP2", "IdSP3"),
               names_to = "especie",
               values_to = "id_especie")
```

En este punto, las columnas IdSP1,IdSP2 y IdSP3, pasaran a una sola columna, también podrías volver a realizar este procedimiento para pasar a una columna las ocupaciones

```
df2 = df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("OcuSP1", "OcuSP2", "OcuSP3"),
               names_to = "Tipo_ocupacion",
               values_to = "valor_ocupacion")
```

Finalmente ya podrías realizar un group_by() ya sea por el id y tipo de ocupacion para posteriormente hacer el summarise() segun tus necesidades.

Comment: Hola @Bastián, gracias por tu respuesta, me sirvió para generar 1 columna con todos los valores, pero ahora se me genera otro problema con los ```IdSP```  ya que se me genera una especie con ID de ```0```. Creo que si cambio ese 0 por un ```NA``` podia hacer el ```summarise```. Pero no estoy seguro...

Comment: Hola @Rodrigo , es natural que se te genere una especie con id 0 ya que al pasar las 3 a columnas, habían algunas que tenían id 0, ahora si no te interesan las que tengan 0 las puedes eliminar con : df2 %>% filter(id_especie != 0)

Comment: Hola @Bastian Andres, lo pude solucionar al final, gracias por tu idea. Un saludo!

Comment: me alegro mucho que pudieras solucionarlo, te pido que pongas que la respeta fue útil :)